# How to append $ when user enter any amount into the editText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I my application when user enter any numberic value in `EditText` then $ `append()` before text.
Any help would be greatly appreciated...thankss a lot...

Comment: I have used TextWatcher but it is not working

Comment: You want to display the $ sign on the screen as they type?

Comment: you did it wrong way then

Comment: @NeetuShrivastava Show us code what you have tried so far.

Comment: I used this code :public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

   // final EditText editText = (EditText) view;
   editable.append("$");
   MainActivity.this.edit.setText(editable);

  }                                                                    Application crashes.

Comment: You are probably getting a `StackOverFlowError` when you do this

Comment: crashes? and you don't know the reason of that crash?

Comment: got StackOverFlowError this error

Comment: so read the docs of TextWatcher again, they explain everything why you got the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) as follows:

```
EditText editbox = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
editbox.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s){

            if(s.toString().length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(0) != '$'){
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                b = b.reverse();
                b.append('$');
                b = b.reverse();
                editbox.setText(b);
                editbox.setSelection(editbox.getText().length());
            }



            int counter = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                if (s.toString().charAt(i) == '$') {
                    counter++;
                }
            }
            if (counter > 1) {
                String str = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
                str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
                b = b.reverse();
                b.append('$');
                b = b.reverse();
                edit.setText(b);
                edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length());
            } else {

                int spaceCount = 0;

                for (int i = 0; i < s.toString().length(); i++) {
                    if (s.toString().charAt(i) == ' ') {
                        spaceCount++;
                    }
                }
                if (spaceCount > 0) {
                    String str = s.toString().replace("$", "").trim();
                    str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
                    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(str);
                    edit.setText(b);
                    edit.setSelection(edit.getText().length());
                }
            }


        }
    });
```

Another approach would be to combine a [`TextWatcher`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher) with a regular expression of some sort.

Comment: One line `editbox.setText("$"+editbox.getText().toString());` would be fine

Comment: That would add the "$" symbol to the text every time the text changes... ;)

Comment: This should put $ sign in each and every character.

Comment: I am saying instead of your lines from `StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder(s.toString());
                b = b.reverse();
                b.append('$');
                b = b.reverse();
                editbox.setText(b);` a single line of `editbox.setText("$"+editbox.getText().toString());` would have been fine

Comment: @GirishNair This single line not work. onTextChanged() is not a place to modify text of EditText.

Comment: @Prince : I just checked the code, cerebro 4 lines were replaced by my single line and the output is same(Even though it not what Neetu Shrivastava wanted). please check it from your side if you think its wrong

Comment: @cerebro : The output is wrong there are repetitive `$` signs

Comment: @Prince : Sometimes we could read and write some code based on our experience without testing it.

Comment: We need to tell other user if we are confident and damn sure about issue after testing, because if without tested we may wrong sometimes.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. I have added the [tested] code with a small modification and it should now work ....

Comment: @Prince : I was confident, but you reputation of 5k mislead me to check it, thinking you might have spotted some error

Comment: @cerebro : The app crashes when you start deleting it, change the if condition like this `if(s.toString().length() > 0 && s.toString().charAt(0) != '$'){`

Comment: @Girish: I was aware of the issue and had almost fixed it, but you beat me to it!

Comment: @cerebo this code is failed when user copy the text with dollar and erase all text except dollar then again paste the old text then two $ are there

Comment: what do you mean by copy the text with dollar

Comment: suppose first time user entered $2435 then he copy this text and erase the text remaining text in editText is $ then he paste then old text now text is $$2435 in editText.

Answer (score -1):

Use the following code

```
ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(ed.getText().toString().length()>1)
            {
                ed.setText("$"+ed.getText().toString());
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: changing the text inside textwatcher is that recommended??

Comment: This is not solution.